# I can not install com0com, a digitally signed driver is required

Tags: drivers, installation, windows-vista, code-signing, null-modem

I tried to install [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) - a null modem emulator - on Windows Vista, but failed because Windows Vista doesn't let me install a driver that is not digitally signed.

I followed these instructions found in the readme file:

1. Inactivate UAC
2. Run `bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON`
3. Reboot the computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running `bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON` in an administrator command prompt (Run as Administrator). Or try: http://www.ngohq.com/home.php?page=dseo instead.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I wasn't logged in as an Administrator when I run the command the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Is 32 or 64 bits Vista? I remember reading in the OSR mailing list that unsigned drivers can not in any way be installed in vista 64 bit.
Hope this helps.

Comment: It's 64 bit. I got it working now, see the answer by BloodPhilia.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the driver signing issue on Windows 8, the `bcdedit` answer above doesn't seem to work because Windows 8 has some sort of new Secure Boot policy that prevents running that command successfully, even as admin (on my machine, at least).

What worked for me was running `shutdown /r /o /t 00` as admin, then selecting `Troubleshoot`, then `Advanced options`, then `Startup Settings`. Click the `Restart` button to restart and enter the `Startup Settings` menu, then select option #7 (`Disable driver signature enforcement`). After restarting, Windows should now allow installation of the `com0com` drivers (though it shows big warning messages that the drivers are untrusted).

(I found the details on getting into the advanced startup settings [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/4924-advanced-startup-settings-boot-windows-8-a.html).)